# How to install Delphi JEDI manually

Tags: delphi, msbuild, jedi

I'm currently trying to set up a build process on a build server and I'm having some trouble installing JEDI with MSBuild. I'm using the Delphi XE2 compiler and based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33564315/how-to-build-a-delphi-project-in-teamcity) Stackoverflow thread I have created the following batch file that I use.

```
@echo off
:::
:::Build Delphi Project with MSBuild
:::

echo.
echo Setting up Delphi XE2 environment
echo.

SET BDS=C:\DelphiXE2
SET BDSBIN=%BDS%\bin
SET BDSLIB=%BDS%\lib
SET BDSTMP=%BDS%\temp
SET BDSAPPDATA=%APPDATA%\Embarcadero\BDS\9.0

IF NOT EXIST "%BDSAPPDATA%" MKDIR "%BDSAPPDATA%"
COPY /Y /B /V "%BDSTMP%\EnvOptions.proj" "%BDSAPPDATA%\EnvOptions.proj"

echo.
echo Build Delphi Project with MSBuild from Visual Studio 2017
echo.

SET MSBUILD_EXE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe

"%MSBUILD_EXE%" %1 /t:%~2 /p:Config=%~3;Platform=%~4
```

I then call

`compile.bat ".\Jedi\JCL\packages\JclPackagesD160.groupproj" "Clean;Build"`

which works fine (atleast without any errors) and after that

`compile.bat ".\Jedi\JVCL\packages\D16 Packages.groupproj" "Clean;Build"`

But the second call fails because `jedi/jedi.inc` can not be found. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check the .dproj file(s). Is the subdirectory containing the jedi.inc file included in the search path? Is the file actually there? (It used to be in its own svn repository on sourceforge and included as an svn:external. No idea how they have solved this with git nowadays.)

Comment: Actually the jedi.inc is not there at all. But when I run the installer instead of doing it manually everything works. So the missing file can't be the problem I guess