# "error: MSB4040 There is no target in the project" when using MSbuild+Delphi10.2

Tags: powershell, delphi, jenkins, msbuild, jenkins-pipeline

I'm automating the build of a Delphi 10.2 project
I'm using msbuild with .net 4.0.30319

I'm running rsvars.bat to set the environment variables and then call MSBuild

```
start-process "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin\rsvars.bat"

MSBuild Modulos/COM/PCOM.dproj
```

Probably the solution will be something simple and basic that I didn't pay attention to and I'll be mulling over it for days after it's solved

I found some articles related to the topic, but none were able to solve my problem.
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342859/error-msb4040-there-is-no-target-in-the-project-when-using-msbuilddelphi2009`
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33564315/how-to-build-a-delphi-project-in-teamcity`

I manage to simulate the error through the windows powershell
[error in the windows powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTNDm.png)

If i run it through the command prompt I get success, but running through Jenkins does not object success.

Comment: Have you a BDS variable where you execute it ?

Comment: No, I don't have

Comment: Create one with your RAD Studio path

Comment: Correction in rsvars.bat, the BDS variable is already being set, with the path to RAD Studio



SET BDS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0

Comment: Try adding SET BDSBIN=rad_path\bin and SET BDSLIB=rad_path\lib

Comment: Even adding both did not work

Comment: I assume all path are correct ? Try run MsBuild from the project folder

Comment: Yes the paths are correct, because if I run the same commands with cmd it works, but when I run them with powershell or Jenkins I have this problem